# How fast is a moth?

Tags: science, lexx

I am currently re-re-watching Lexx season 4 episode 2, and it seems like the moth is extraordinarily fast. It passes a shuttle, and seems to arrive on Earth in a matter of hours.

My understanding is that the  NASA trip from Earth to the moon required around 3-4 days.

They did not take any food or water, so I am guessing less than 8 hours.